# Why [programming-languages]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why do we have [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages)? Glancing at the first 2 pages the question quality seems low. Seems to me that it could be partly related to [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) and a very meta tag which are discouraged.

Comment: It seems to have a valid use case when asking questions about programming languages themselves. Such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages). This seems to not be a good use case for language-agnostic.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is linked at the bottom of the tag info.

Comment: @DavisBroda thats way too broad of a question IMO

Comment: Even if not too broad, the tag does nothing to categorize the question or make it easier to find. The other tags, `static-typing` and `dynamic-typing` are sufficient.